# What does the "static" mean in Java?

Tags: java

I'm wondering why do people use "static" for example, `public static final String`

Comment: Learn java before using LibGDX, it's essential for it

Comment: This shows literally zero research effort.

Comment: This isn't a game dev question, it's a general programming question. Furthermore, it's already been asked & answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/413898/950488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` for a member variable means that it is shared across all instances of the class. It also means that you don't need an instance of the class to access the field.

```
public class Foo {
  public int A = 10;
  public static int B = 20;
}


public class Bar {
   public void FooBar() {
      Foo.B = 30; // Valid, sets the static instance
      Foo.A = 40; // Invalid, accessing A not through an instance

      Foo f1 = new Foo();
      Foo f2 = new Foo();

      f1.B = 100;
      f2.B = 200;

      System.out.println("f1.B = " + f1.B); // Prints 200, not 100
      System.out.println("f2.B = " + f2.B); // Prints 200
   }
}
```

People often use `public static final` when creating constant values that are to be easily shared and accessed by many parts of the game.

The [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) cover the `static` keyword in more detail.

Comment: Please avoid answering duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Really, all functions in all classes are "static" in the sense that they do not change at runtime, and there is one instance in memory of each, regardless of how many instances of that class exist.

If you were ever to write code in C, you'd have better insight into this. C has only one type of function, and does not artificially divide functions ("methods") into distinct types. Yet you can do everything in C that you can in higher level languages like C++, C#, or Java (but with more effort in some cases).

So from the perspective of "why?" - Mainly because OO languages introduced the concept in order to draw a distinction between things (in classes) that always exist (static, compile time stuff) and stuff that is dynamically created (instantiated at runtime). This was done differently because while C assumes there is only one any function of a given name, C++ may have many instances of the same class. At least for class data members, this distinction needs to be drawn - there can be many `myObj.instanceVariable` but only one `MyClass.staticVariable`. The distinction seems to have been made simply to match the way we view methods to the way we view data members, which are their conceptual siblings, OO languages.